# Converting array (produced by "table") to data frame in r or s-plus

Tags: arrays, r

I am trying to convert an array that was produced by the "table" function into a normal data frame within a function.  I've tried `as.data.frame`, and get `is.data.frame=TRUE`.  However, the object is still an array with an extra dim.  This causes problems when I merge it with a data frame, and I end up with a single column of the data frame having array dimensions.  How can I coerce the object to a simple data frame? The extra dim contains only the rownames.  I've tried setting rownames to null to no avail.

Comment: Can you try this first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758961/how-to-convert-a-table-to-a-data-frame-in-r

Comment: What does your `table()` output look like? A reproducible example is required.

Answer (score 1):

A reproducible example will help if you can provide one, but I've had this problem before too. There's a number of solutions to this, none of them are perfect.

```
DF <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(table(whatev))) ## makes a data frame w/ one column
                                              ## and rownames = names(table)
DF$V2 <- rownames(DF)            ## or as.numeric(rownames(DF)) if you want
rownames(DF) <- NULL             ## no need for them anymore
```

Also

```
DF <- data.frame(V1 = as.vector(names(table(whatever))), V2 = as.numeric(table(w.e))
```