# Need help for R coding on aggregate function

Tags: r, aggregate, rows

I want to aggregate a table data.
I have data as below.

```
x                y
served           4d0e1e88-60a4-4e9e-f914-50fab6039d73
close            6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018
served           6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018
switchProduct    6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018
served           6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018
switchProduct    6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473019
switchProduct    6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018
Click            6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018
switchProduct    6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018
Click            6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473014
```

I am trying to aggregate this as shown below.

```
y                                 Click   close  served switchProduct
4d0e1e88-60a4-4e9e-f914-50fab6039d73            1   
6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473014    1           
6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018    1   1   2   3
6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473019                1
```

But on trying to get the above expected output am getting this output

```
aggregate(x$x,list(x$x,x$y),length)

y                                   x
4d0e1e88-60a4-4e9e-f914-50fab6039d73    1
6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473014    1
6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018    7
6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473019    1
```

Comment: `with(df, table(y, x))`?

Comment: sorry, i have used the dummy column names.The column names i used are x y are action & Userid

Comment: Not in your example though. See my solution - if you just have the two columns in your data.frame, then for data.frame `x`, do `t(table(x))`

Comment: y -> Userid x -> Action

Comment: Just change the name of your data frame and variables accordingly. `with(the-name-of-the-data-frame, table(variable-to-appear-in-rows, variable-to-appear-in-columns))`

Comment: jbaums i have 23 columns in my data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `table` rather than `aggregate`.

```
d <- read.table(text='x                y
served           4d0e1e88-60a4-4e9e-f914-50fab6039d73
close            6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018
served           6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018
switchProduct    6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018
served           6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018
switchProduct    6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473019
switchProduct    6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018
Click            6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018
switchProduct    6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018
Click            6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473014', header=TRUE)

t(table(d))

                                      x
y                                      Click close served switchProduct
  4d0e1e88-60a4-4e9e-f914-50fab6039d73     0     0      1             0
  6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473014     1     0      0             0
  6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473018     1     1      2             3
  6ad31901-ed0d-4a12-a686-962bbd473019     0     0      0             1
```

Comment: I have a data with 21 variables out of that i need above two variables so i have sent only two variables. but i will try your method and come to you. thanks

Comment: How can i save this to a data frame. is it possible to save this into data frame. t(table(d))

Comment: Try `as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(d)))` (courtesy of [@VictorVanHee](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10759011/489704))