# Using base::table as argument of plyr::ddply

Tags: r, plyr

Not sure how to domesticate `ddply` here by summarising my gender counts for countries. I have this data frame

```
df <- data.frame(country = c("Italy", "Germany", "Italy", "USA","Poland"),
                 gender = c("male", "female", "male", "female", "female"))
```

And I want a dataframe where each row details how many males and females each country has. Yet

```
ddply(df,~country,table)

   country female male
1  Germany      1    0
2  Germany      0    0
3  Germany      0    0
4  Germany      0    0
5    Italy      0    0
6    Italy      0    2
7    Italy      0    0
8    Italy      0    0
9   Poland      0    0
10  Poland      0    0
11  Poland      1    0
12  Poland      0    0
13     USA      0    0
14     USA      0    0
15     USA      0    0
16     USA      1    0
```

although it produces the desired result it also adds three extra line for each group. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. Not sure is the most elegant.

```
df <- data.frame(country = c("Italy", "Germany", "Italy", "USA","Poland"),
                     gender = c("male", "female", "male", "female", NA))

ddply(df, .(country), summarise, 
      female=sum(gender=="female",na.rm = TRUE),
      male=sum(gender=="male", na.rm = TRUE),
      na=sum(is.na(gender)))
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to use `ddply` for this.  It's more work than is necessary.  Maybe look at `table(df, useNA = "always")`.  The result is almost identical.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you wanted simply

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))
```

Thanks to: [How to convert a table to a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758961/how-to-convert-a-table-to-a-data-frame-in-r)

But to answer your question about why you got the output you did...

`table` is based on factor levels, not on the values in your vector. So if you run

```
df[df$country=="Germany",]$country

[1] Germany
Levels: Germany Italy Poland USA
```

You can see that after subsetting, the country vector still has all four levels, but only one value. Then when you run `table`, it summarizes for each of those levels, even if they are not in the vector.

```
table(df[df$country=="Germany",])

         gender
country   female male
  Germany      1    0
  Italy        0    0
  Poland       0    0
  USA          0    0
```

When debugging `ddply`, always try out your function on one of the subsets it will create from your data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already in `plyr`, why not use the `count` function?

```
> library(plyr)
> count(df)
#   country gender freq
# 1 Germany female    1
# 2   Italy   male    2
# 3  Poland female    1
# 4     USA female    1
```

Or in base R, a `table`

```
> ( tb <- table(df) )
#          gender
# country   female male
#   Germany      1    0
#   Italy        0    2
#   Poland       1    0
#   USA          1    0
```

**ADDED**: Per OPs comment below, to turn the above table into a data frame, you can manipulate, use, and change its attributes.

```
> as.data.frame(cbind(country = rownames(tb), unclass(tb)),
                row.names = "NULL")
#   country female male
# 1 Germany      1    0
# 2   Italy      0    2
# 3  Poland      1    0
# 4     USA      1    0
```

Comment: From the object `table(df)` how do you create a data.frame keeping the aggregation by country?

Comment: @CptNemo - I've added that to my answer.