# Convert a table with missing values to a data frame of the same structure as the original table?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

**Convert a table with missing values to a data frame of the same structure as the original table?**

Neither of the following methods work, as they either change the structure or do not work with missing values:

```
t1  <- with( mtcars, table( gear,cyl, exclude = NULL  ) ) # the table


     data.frame(t1)
     as.data.frame(t1)
     as.data.frame.table(t1)
     as.data.frame.matrix(t1)
```

The following code works but I was hoping for a solution involving less writing:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast( data.frame(t1), value.var = "Freq", formula = gear ~ cyl )
```

The solutions to this SO question does not work with missing values:
[How to convert a table to a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758961/how-to-convert-a-table-to-a-data-frame-in-r)

maybe I'm just too lazy. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table); library(tidyr)
t1  <- with( mtcars, table( gear,cyl, exclude = NULL  ) )
as.data.table(t1) %>% spread(cyl, N)
#   gear 4 6  8 NA
# 1    3 1 2 12  0
# 2    4 8 4  0  0
# 3    5 2 1  2  0
# 4 <NA> 0 0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `NA` that you see in the result of "t1" is actually an `NA` value in the `dimnames`, so you can't directly use `as.data.frame.matrix`.

I guess if you do this a lot and want to save typing, the best recourse might be to write a function like the following:

```
dimFixDF <- function(intable) {
  as.data.frame.matrix(`dimnames<-`(intable, lapply(dimnames(intable), 
    function(x) {
      ifelse(is.na(x), "<NA>", x)
    })))
}
```

When you use it, it replaces the `NA` values in the `dimnames` with the character representation, and then it converts it to a `data.frame` with `as.data.frame.matrix`.

```
dimFixDF(t1)
#      4 6  8 <NA>
# 3    1 2 12    0
# 4    8 4  0    0
# 5    2 1  2    0
# <NA> 0 0  0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with a matrix, you can do this in `base` R by setting the object's class to `'matrix'`:

```
t1  <- with(mtcars, table(gear, cyl, exclude = NULL))
class(t1) <- 'matrix'

t1
#       cyl
# gear   4 6  8 <NA>
#   3    1 2 12    0
#   4    8 4  0    0
#   5    2 1  2    0
#   <NA> 0 0  0    0  

str(t1)
#  int [1:4, 1:4] 1 8 2 0 2 4 1 0 12 0 ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ gear: chr [1:4] "3" "4" "5" NA
#   ..$ cyl : chr [1:4] "4" "6" "8" NA
```