# unsuccessful (invisible?) conversion to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-structures

To learn R, I tried importing data (about spam) contained in a plain text file.

I used the table function, and then tried to convert the corresponding object to a data frame, using two answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758961/how-to-convert-a-table-to-a-data-frame) question.

Here is the code.

```
file <- "./spam.data.txt"

spamd <- read.table(file, sep = "" , header = F, stringsAsFactors= F)
spamd <- as.data.frame(spamd)
typeof(spamd)    # list

spamd <- read.table(file, sep = "" , header = F, stringsAsFactors= F)
spamd <- as.data.frame.matrix(spamd)
typeof(spamd)    # list
```

Why is it that in both case, `typeof()` returns `list`? Why not dataframe?

Thanks

Comment: You need to learn more about data structures in R. Check `class(spamd)`. Note that `read.table` is documented to return a data.frame. No conversion necessary,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data frames are really just lists of vectors. From [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#data-frames) by Hadley:

> Because a `data.frame` is an S3 class, its type reflects the underlying vector used to build it: the list. To check if an object is a data frame, use `class()` or test explicitly with `is.data.frame()`.

You should note that calling `length()` on a data frame therefore returns the number of columns, not the number of rows. Try:

```
length(spamd)
ncol(spamd)
nrow(spamd)
```