# How do I extract values from a table by name?

Tags: r

When I use the table method, I get a count of how many of each element appears. e.g.

```
tab = table(data.frame(c('a','a','b','c')))
```

Gives me the value:

```
a b c 
2 1 1
```

I don't understand what this data structure is though or how to use it. If I want to grab a value from it, I can use `tab['a']`, but this gives:

```
a 
2
```

When I check the type of `tab['a']`, it just tells me it's an `integer`. Why does it have the `a` attached to it? How do I get just the value (2)?

Comment: Try `class(tab); str(tab)` also see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758961/how-to-convert-a-table-to-a-data-frame)

Comment: `unname(tab['a'])` to get only the value.

Comment: or try tab[['a']]