# Rownames to column in table not working, converts to list or as.data.frame introduces extra rows

Tags: r, dataframe

My data is a count table of categorical variables from a larger data frame.  My goal is to plot the number of instances of alive/dead for each treatment in that data frame.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
  Treatment Plate Sex                 Days Status
1          1     1   U                  NA   Dead
2          1     1   U                  NA   Dead
3          1     1   U                  NA   Dead
4          1     1   U                  NA   Alive
5          1     1   U                  NA   Dead
6          1     1   U                  NA   Dead
```

The data table looks like this:

> table(Subset$Treatment, Subset$Status)

```
           Dead Still_kicking
  1         144             0
  3         141             3
  7         144             0
  10        105            39
  13         69             3
  Control    12            60
  Control2    2            70
```

I want the row names to column (prefer a one-liner).  When I try to add the column I get this:

```
> Status$names <- rownames(Status)
Warning message:
In Status$names <- rownames(Status) : Coercing LHS to a list
> Status
[[1]]
[1] 144

[[2]]
[1] 141

[[3]]
[1] 144
```

If I convert to a data frame I get extra rows:

```
> Status <- data.frame(Status)
> Status
       Var1          Var2 Freq
1         1          Dead  144
2         3          Dead  141
3         7          Dead  144
4        10          Dead  105
5        13          Dead   69
6   Control          Dead   12
7  Control2          Dead    2
8         1 Still_kicking    0
9         3 Still_kicking    3
10        7 Still_kicking    0
11       10 Still_kicking   39
12       13 Still_kicking    3
13  Control Still_kicking   60
14 Control2 Still_kicking   70
```

Comment: One thing you need to note is a table is a restructured arranged dataframe. eg so the rownames are not observational units but rather variables as well

Comment: you can also use  `as.data.frame.matrix(Status)`  this will create a data.frame exactly looking like your table. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758961/how-to-convert-a-table-to-a-data-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `unclass`.

In below example I have used `mtcars` dataset to convert `table(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$am)`

```
     0  1
  4  3  8
  6  4  3
  8 12  2
```

into dataframe format.

`tibble::rownames_to_column` can be used to add rownames as the first column.

```
library(tibble)
rownames_to_column(data.frame(unclass(table(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$am))), 
                   "rownames_col")
```

Output is:

```
  rownames_col X0 X1
1            4  3  8
2            6  4  3
3            8 12  2
```