# Display of frequencies table is altered between console and RStudio viewer

Tags: r, rstudio

When creating a table for frequencies, I get different displays between console output and RStudio viewer. Important to note, the information remains the same across, it's just the display that's different.

### Generate Data

```r
id <- rep(1:20, each = 200)

colors <- sample(c("red", 
                   "blue", 
                   "green", 
                   "yellow", 
                   "orange", 
                   "brown", "
                   white", 
                   "pink"), 
                 size = 4000, replace = TRUE)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, colors))

tally <- with(df, table(id, colors))

> tally

    colors
id   \n                   white blue brown green orange pink red yellow
  1                          33   22    33    25     21   23  24     19
  10                         16   17    34    30     25   24  33     21
  11                         30   27    28    28     22   18  26     21
  12                         25   24    21    25     21   35  23     26
  13                         22   28    22    30     21   28  29     20
  14                         25   24    21    28     30   23  24     25
  15                         26   20    20    20     35   32  26     21
  16                         32   21    14    33     28   14  25     33
  17                         29   24    31    23     21   28  14     30
  18                         28   30    22    22     20   23  26     29
  19                         22   30    25    22     27   34  16     24
  2                          21   30    19    18     37   23  32     20
  20                         27   26    24    36     25   16  19     27
  3                          25   27    24    26     20   27  22     29
  4                          26   23    28    25     22   28  25     23
  5                          30   26    16    28     21   31  25     23
  6                          31   30    21    26     20   25  24     23
  7                          30   23    25    28     28   24  21     21
  8                          31   18    37    14     28   25  26     21
  9                          22   22    23    32     22   21  28     30
```

### However, when using `View()` I get the data displayed in a different format

```r
View(tally)
```

[image: rstudio_viewer]

Is there a way to make the Viewer show the data in the same format as in the console (where columns correspond to the colors)?

### EDIT 25-AUG-2019

From @camille's comments below, I've learned that this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10758961/6105259). The point conveyed is that RStudio's viewer knows how to display data frames properly but not tables. Therefore, the solution provided in the old post would suggest to use either the generic `as.data.frame()` or the more specific `as.data.frame.table()`/`as.data.frame.matrix()` to convert the table to a data frame, and RStudio's viewer should subsequently be able to render the data properly as in the original table's layout.

Unfortunately, neither of the proposed functions works for me. Also evident from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758961/how-to-convert-a-table-to-a-data-frame#comment79115374_10759011) that the solution provided in that post might have ceased from working, and it's not just my case. The question and solution posted in 2012, so perhaps something has changed between then and now?

For the sake of demonstrating the behavior I'm talking about:

```r
tally <- with(df, table(id, colors))

is.table(tally)
[1] TRUE

> tally

    colors
id   \n                   white blue brown green orange pink red yellow
  1                          33   22    33    25     21   23  24     19
  10                         16   17    34    30     25   24  33     21
  11                         30   27    28    28     22   18  26     21
  12                         25   24    21    25     21   35  23     26
  13                         22   28    22    30     21   28  29     20
  14                         25   24    21    28     30   23  24     25
  15                         26   20    20    20     35   32  26     21
  16                         32   21    14    33     28   14  25     33
  17                         29   24    31    23     21   28  14     30
  18                         28   30    22    22     20   23  26     29
  19                         22   30    25    22     27   34  16     24
  2                          21   30    19    18     37   23  32     20
  20                         27   26    24    36     25   16  19     27
  3                          25   27    24    26     20   27  22     29
  4                          26   23    28    25     22   28  25     23
  5                          30   26    16    28     21   31  25     23
  6                          31   30    21    26     20   25  24     23
  7                          30   23    25    28     28   24  21     21
  8                          31   18    37    14     28   25  26     21
  9                          22   22    23    32     22   21  28     30

> tally <- as.data.frame.table(tally)

> is.table(tally)
[1] FALSE

> is.data.frame(tally)
[1] TRUE

> tally

    id                     colors Freq
1    1 \n                   white   33
2   10 \n                   white   16
3   11 \n                   white   30
4   12 \n                   white   25
5   13 \n                   white   22
6   14 \n                   white   25
7   15 \n                   white   26
8   16 \n                   white   32
9   17 \n                   white   29
10  18 \n                   white   28
11  19 \n                   white   22
12   2 \n                   white   21
13  20 \n                   white   27
14   3 \n                   white   25
15   4 \n                   white   26
16   5 \n                   white   30
17   6 \n                   white   31
18   7 \n                   white   30
19   8 \n                   white   31
20   9 \n                   white   22
21   1                       blue   22
22  10                       blue   17
23  11                       blue   27
24  12                       blue   24
25  13                       blue   28
26  14                       blue   24
27  15                       blue   20
28  16                       blue   21
29  17                       blue   24
30  18                       blue   30
31  19                       blue   30
32   2                       blue   30
33  20                       blue   26
34   3                       blue   27
35   4                       blue   23
36   5                       blue   26
37   6                       blue   30
38   7                       blue   23
39   8                       blue   18
40   9                       blue   22
41   1                      brown   33
42  10                      brown   34
43  11                      brown   28
44  12                      brown   21
45  13                      brown   22
46  14                      brown   21
47  15                      brown   20
48  16                      brown   14
49  17                      brown   31
50  18                      brown   22
51  19                      brown   25
52   2                      brown   19
53  20                      brown   24
54   3                      brown   24
55   4                      brown   28
56   5                      brown   16
57   6                      brown   21
58   7                      brown   25
59   8                      brown   37
60   9                      brown   23
61   1                      green   25
62  10                      green   30
63  11                      green   28
64  12                      green   25
65  13                      green   30
66  14                      green   28
67  15                      green   20
68  16                      green   33
69  17                      green   23
70  18                      green   22
71  19                      green   22
72   2                      green   18
73  20                      green   36
74   3                      green   26
75   4                      green   25
76   5                      green   28
77   6                      green   26
78   7                      green   28
79   8                      green   14
80   9                      green   32
81   1                     orange   21
82  10                     orange   25
83  11                     orange   22
84  12                     orange   21
85  13                     orange   21
86  14                     orange   30
87  15                     orange   35
88  16                     orange   28
89  17                     orange   21
90  18                     orange   20
91  19                     orange   27
92   2                     orange   37
93  20                     orange   25
94   3                     orange   20
95   4                     orange   22
96   5                     orange   21
97   6                     orange   20
98   7                     orange   28
99   8                     orange   28
100  9                     orange   22
101  1                       pink   23
102 10                       pink   24
103 11                       pink   18
104 12                       pink   35
105 13                       pink   28
106 14                       pink   23
107 15                       pink   32
108 16                       pink   14
109 17                       pink   28
110 18                       pink   23
111 19                       pink   34
112  2                       pink   23
113 20                       pink   16
114  3                       pink   27
115  4                       pink   28
116  5                       pink   31
117  6                       pink   25
118  7                       pink   24
119  8                       pink   25
120  9                       pink   21
121  1                        red   24
122 10                        red   33
123 11                        red   26
124 12                        red   23
125 13                        red   29
126 14                        red   24
127 15                        red   26
128 16                        red   25
129 17                        red   14
130 18                        red   26
131 19                        red   16
132  2                        red   32
133 20                        red   19
134  3                        red   22
135  4                        red   25
136  5                        red   25
137  6                        red   24
138  7                        red   21
139  8                        red   26
140  9                        red   28
141  1                     yellow   19
142 10                     yellow   21
143 11                     yellow   21
144 12                     yellow   26
145 13                     yellow   20
146 14                     yellow   25
147 15                     yellow   21
148 16                     yellow   33
149 17                     yellow   30
150 18                     yellow   29
151 19                     yellow   24
152  2                     yellow   20
153 20                     yellow   27
154  3                     yellow   29
155  4                     yellow   23
156  5                     yellow   23
157  6                     yellow   23
158  7                     yellow   21
159  8                     yellow   21
160  9                     yellow   30
```

As can be seen above, when I use `as.data.frame.table`, not only does it not solve my problem, but it makes the unwanted layout of data to now appear in console as well.

Any ideas how to convert to a data frame while preserving the format I had when originally running `with(df, table(id, colors))` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the class of `tally`: it's a table, not a data frame. `View(tally)` is converting the information, based on the attributes of a table object, to a data frame to display. Docs for `View` tell you that it first coerces to a data frame; call `as.data.frame(tally)` to see that `View` shows the same thing

Comment: I'm still quite confused. When I convert `tally` to a data frame using `as.data.frame()`, `View()` still shows the data as organized by Freq column rather than one column per color.  So the issue remains regardless of the object's class being a table or a data frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a table to a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758961/how-to-convert-a-table-to-a-data-frame)

Comment: `View` needs a `data.frame` to display the table in the viewer pane. It does not work for `table`. It's an implementation necessity.

Comment: I've updated the post to reflect my attempt to convert the table to a data frame, but still without success.