# Turning table into data frame

Tags: r

[image: table]

I attached a picture, but I currently have a table and would like to turn it into a data frame. However, when I tried

```r
as.data.frame(pred_table)
```

it returned something completely different. I would like a data frame that has the first column as name, the second titled x, the third y, etc. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try `as.data.frame.matrix(pred_table)` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758961/how-to-convert-a-table-to-a-data-frame

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Code fences are not single-quotes `'''` followed immediately by code, they are three backticks with a language on a line on its own, in this case `\`\`\`lang-r` and then a newline. Similarly, the code end-fence is three backticks (no language), as in `\`\`\``.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: What do the names `x` and `y` have to do with that table? (Perhaps it has something to do with how you formed that table or the original dataset?)

Comment: @RonakShah that works great, but there doesn't appear to be a column for name, only 0:4. Any ideas on how to fix that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you can do something like this :

```
#Convert to dataframe
data <- as.data.frame.matrix(pred_table)
#Assign column names
names(data) <- letters[seq_along(data)]
#Convert rownames to column
data$names <- rownames(data)
#Remove row names. 
rownames(data) <- NULL
```