# How to make a data.frame with one-dimensional output of table()?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish

```
> table(mtcars$cyl)

 4  6  8 
11  7 14
```

And I need it in this format,

```
mtcars_table <- data.frame(
  "4" = c(11),
  "6" = c(6),
  "8" = c(14))

> print(mtcars_table)
  X4 X6 X8
1 11  6 14
```

I pretty much need the categorical variables as my columns and the counts as my row.
If there is a dplyr way to this easier i'm open to it as well.

Comment: Updated the title to make clearer contrast with a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758961/how-to-convert-a-table-to-a-data-frame.

Comment: Maybe using `t.data.frame` function.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this:

```
#Code
mytable <- data.frame(rbind(table(mtcars$cyl)))
```

Output:

```
  X4 X6 X8
1 11  7 14
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# unclass() + t()
as.data.frame(t(unclass(table(mtcars$cyl))))
#    4 6  8
# 1 11 7 14

# as.list()
as.data.frame(as.list(table(mtcars$cyl)))
  X4 X6 X8
1 11  7 14

# Super fast
data.table::setDF(as.list(table(mtcars$cyl)))[]
```